# Facebook Page Tab App OAuth - test if fresh app install

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a page tab app.  The authorization works fine - the user clicks the authorize button on the app, the OAuth dialog pops up, they authorize the app, it redirects back to the page tab and the user goes about their merry way, using the app.

I need to know one thing, and for the life of me I cannot find a real answer - is it possible to identify the one http request that occurs immediately after the user authorizes the app?  I simply want to log the user's data when a user authorizes the app, without having to hit the database and test if the facebook user id has already been logged.  You'd think this would be easy...

THank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do with help of the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/) how to handle authroization in page tab.

**simply, when user comes to app**
- check user_id exits in signed request, if not exist, then he has not authorized.
- Store some variable in session
- when user logs in, check whether session variable exists or not. if exists, its a fresh install.

Comment: Thank you Venu.  I'm so used to testing if an app is authorized it didn't occur to me to test if it is NOT authorized first :)  It seemed to me that Facebook would have the OAuth dialog post a parameter to the iframed app to detect fresh installs, but this will work just fine :)  Thanks again!